# How to creat a Joomla Form

Tags: forms, joomla

How Can I create form in joomla on which on clicking the image it will got to the next page for next question. Again clicking one of the image as answer it will proceed like this and finally validate the form 
See the sample design of my form that I want to make it in joomla
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va8Zs.jpg)

Comment: Please make an [edit] showing what you've tried and I would encourage you to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If this is a set of questions, you can use the [Joomla! Quiz Deluxe Component](https://www.joomplace.com/elearning-extensions/joomla-quiz-deluxe.html) to setup multiple choice questions with images as the answers.

If this is an eCommerce/order form, you can try [ChronoForms](http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads/chronoforms). It is a bit more complicated to set up, but has greater flexibility.